# How to have a different layout for a grid when there is one row vs 2 rows?

Tags: css

[image]

[image]

This is an example of what my layout looks like for 2 rows on my grid. But if there is only 1 row of three i want it to have a different layout so it is in the center of the screen. Right now it would be where the top layer is and have nothing below it so it look odd be so high up.
Heres the CSS for the Layout:

```
 .grid-con  {
      position: absolute;
      display: grid;
      width: 1000px;
      grid-template-columns: 250px 250px 250px;
      top: 20%;
      padding-top: 5px;
      padding-bottom: 5px;
      gap: 30px;
      color: #fff;
      overflow: hidden;
      justify-content: center;
      right: 10%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

Im stuck on this and have been looking but cant seem to figure out how to have different layouts for the grid length

Comment: Please show us your html structure and how height is defined.

Comment: never mind figured it out

Comment: Why not just centre the grid vertically however many rows it has?

Comment: yeah that makes more sense thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
const gridCon = document.querySelector('.grid-con');
            function adjustGridLayout(){
                const gridConHeight = gridCon.clientHeight;
    
                if (gridConHeight <= 260) {
                    // Change the layout for a height of 200px or less
                    gridCon.style.top = '35%';
                } else{
                    // Change the layout for a height between 200px and 400px
                    gridCon.style.top = '20%';
                } 
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**